Any relation between two KL divergences?
I am using a KL divergence to measure the difference between distributions, but I would like to compare the results to each one another, because the probability distributions I'm measuring are correlated. What is a good measure for comparing two KL divergences on related distributions?
Ex. If I'm looking at some characterization data for a test, let's say X-ray diffraction patterns for a metal sample. I get an XRD pattern of intensity vs. diffraction angle, and can create a probability distribution for that in a reference state (room temp, new sample). I then run the same XRD test on the same sample while I vary temperature, and for that temperature I get a new distribution of my XRD data, and I can calculate the KL divergence for that distribution relative to my reference one.
Let's say I then cold-roll my metal sample, and run the same XRD experiment, and then calculate the KL divergence with the same reference state for those distributions. I have two KL divergence results, and I know that there are variables for the metal sample, temperature vs. strength, that are correlated. Is there any comparison technique between divergences to tell me how much one distribution diverged relative to another? Especially if the variables are interrelated?
Edit: Changing the example to be more specific.

Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm unclear on what you mean by "I calculate the divergence of the distribution of the data due to changing temperature...I look at the divergence of the data due to changing pressure." K-L divergence assess how an empirical distribution differs from another empirical distribution or from a theoretical distribution. It's not clear to me what distribution you are comparing your observations against as temperature or pressure change. Please edit the question to explain that and to say more about what you are trying to accomplish; there might be a better approach.

Absolutely, thanks!

This might better be done with a different method to gauge differences between distributions. As Kullback-Liebler (KL) is a divergence, the triangle inequality need not hold. Thus comparisons like you desire can be tricky.
There are true metrics of differences among distributions that can better agree with intuitive ideas of distances. This page compares the Wasserstein metric and KL divergence. In particular, this answer shows how the Wasserstein "earth mover's" distance can work better than KL when you are expecting gradual changes in the distribution as you alter some underlying parameter (as I suppose would be the case as temperature changes in your situation).
